# Form submits on textinput

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to ReactJs so please bear with me.

**In the following code, I have two forms.**

The upper form works just fine. But, when writing something on the lower form, the upper form submits.

I have tried using defaultValue instead of value but it also did not work.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>ETH to EGP Exchange</h1>

      <div>
        <label>
          Enter Account:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.amount}
          onChange={this.handleChangeBuy}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onClick={this.handleBuy}
        />
      </div>

      <p>Your account: {this.state.value}</p>
      <p>Your account: {this.state.amount}</p>
      <p>Your ETH Balance: {this.state.Eth_Balance}</p>
      <p>Your EGPT Balance: {this.state.EGPT_Balance}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
function render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>ETH to EGP Exchange</h1>

      <div>
        <label>
          Enter Account:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          defaultValue={this.state.amount}
          onChange={() => this.handleChangeBuy}
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onSubmit={this.handleBuy}
        />
      </div>

      <p>Your account: {this.state.value}</p>
      <p>Your account: {this.state.amount}</p>
      <p>Your ETH Balance: {this.state.Eth_Balance}</p>
      <p>Your EGPT Balance: {this.state.EGPT_Balance}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This lets me write in the textbox, but the submit button would not even fire in this case**

Comment: Could you provide the full component?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onsubmit` should be applied to the form as it's the form that gets submitted - not the button